# What will be the transfer function of the block diagram?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

I have tried it for hours but I am not getting the correct answer.

Here is the link to the question: *https://ibb.co/gFhrwCW*
Here is the link to my attempt at solving it: *https://ibb.co/GcMZC13*

Comment: Instead of fishy looking links, post attempts and question inline with the question.

Comment: its just an image hosting website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably attack it this way (a helping start): -

[image]

One of the mistakes you make is in calculating what G2 and G3 in parallel are. They are simply added to each other after making the initial modification shown above.

---

I think you should be able to take it from here. But, if not and given that you have accepted the answer, here's how I would approach it as an exercise: -

[image]

It's looking fairly straightforward now so I'll finish.